# Div não prende ao topo?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma `div` que gostaria que prendesse ao topo quando a div tiver a tocar no topo. Eu tentei fazer [isto](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxo7zpsL/2/), resultou mas a `div` contínua a piscar. O que tem de errado?

### SCRIPT

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var ell = $('.menu').offset().top;
  var ill = $(document).scrollTop();
  var screen = $(window).height();
  var distance = ell - ill;
  if(ell < ill ) {
      $('.menu').css("position", "fixed");
      $('.menu').css("top", "0");
  }else{
    $('.menu').css("position", "relative");
    $('.menu').css("top", "initial");
  }
});
```

### UPDATE

Descobri o problema, uma vez que a `div` fica `fixed`, ficará com a mesma distância do topo como o scroll, sendo assim, vai ficar sempre preso ao topo. Existe como guardar a posição antiga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer assim também:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var ell_height = $('.menu').outerHeight(); // pego altura da div para os cálculos
  var ell = $('.menu').offset().top;
  var ill = $(window).scrollTop();
//  var screen = $(window).height();
  var distance = ell-ill;
  if(distance <= 0 && ill > ell_height) {
      $('.menu').css({
    "position":"fixed",
    "top":"0"
   })
   .text("div posição fixa");
  }else if(ill <= ell_height){
    $('.menu')
 .css("position", "relative")
 .text("div posição normal");
  }
});
```

```css
.menu{
 display: block; background: red; width: 200px; height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role a página
<br /><br />
<div class="menu">
 div posição normal
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta! Exemplo perfeito e funcional.

Comment: @I_like_trains Valeu meu caro! Sucesso!

Answer (score 2):

Descobri como resolver. Invês de carregar a posição da `<div> menu`, carrego-a fora da função do `scroll`, ou seja, o código ficaria assim

```
var ell = $('.menu').offset().top;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var ill = $(document).scrollTop();
  var dif = ill - ell;
   $(".menu").html("Distância Menu: "+ell+"     |    Distância Scroll: "+ill+"     |    Diferença: "+dif);

  if(dif >= 0  ) {
      $('.menu').css("position", "fixed");
      $('.menu').css("top", "0");
  }else{
    $('.menu').css("position", "relative");
    $('.menu').css("top", "initial");
  }
});
```